# Default selected value

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to set default selected value for DropDownList.
SQLString : select * from StatusTypes where StatusDescription ="Queued"

Controller code :

```
TaxAmdViewModel taxAmdViewModel = new TaxAmdViewModel();
{
   taxAmdViewModel.statusTypeDDL = (from a in opsdb.StatusTypes select a.StatusDescription).ToList();
}
```

view page code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label class="control-label">Action</label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.statusTypeDDL, new SelectList(Model.statusTypeDDL, "Description"),  new { @id = "statusAction", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define another property in the TaxAmdViewModel for the selected value. Like this:

```
public class TaxAmdViewModel
{
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    public List<string> statusTypeDDL { get; set; }
}

public class StatusTypes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Then in controller, give it a value which you want to be selected.

```
TaxAmdViewModel taxAmdViewModel = new TaxAmdViewModel();
{
    taxAmdViewModel.statusDescription = "Queued";
    taxAmdViewModel.statusTypeDDL = (from a in opsdb.StatusTypes select a.StatusDescription).ToList();
}
```

And the View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label">Action</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.statusDescription, new SelectList(Model.statusTypeDDL, "Description"), new { @id = "statusAction", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it Worked. Thank you –  @mj1313